# Flutter Dart | How to return different object from class Constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

In `Dart`, is it possible for a `constructor` to cancel object creation and return a different object instead?

Use case:
`Users` contains a static map that maps ids to `User` objects.
When a `User` is initialized, I want the `User` `constructor` to check if `User` with `id` is already created, if so: return existing `User object`, else create a new `User object`

Example (of-course not working):

```
class Users {
  static const Map<String, User> users = {};
}

class User {
 final String id;
 final String firstName;

 User({required id, required firstName}) {
  // If user with id already exists, return that object
  if (Users.users.containsKey(id) {
    return Users.users[id];
  }
 // Else, initialize object and save it in Users.users
  this.id = id; 
  this.firstName = firstName;
  Users.users[id] = this;
 }
}
```

**Question:** IS there any way to get the above pseudo code to work?

Comment: This is what a [`factory` constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors) is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by [jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) you should use a factory constructor. Here's what is mentioned [in the documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#factory-constructors):

> Use the factory keyword when implementing a constructor that doesn’t
> always create a new instance of its class.

And in your case this is exactly what you want. Now here's a code sample that does what you want:

### Code sample

```dart
class Users {
  // Also your Map cannot be const if you want to edit it.
  static Map<String, User> users = {};
}

class User {
  final String id;
  final String firstName;

  /// Base private constructor required to create the User object.
  User._({required this.id, required this.firstName});

  /// Factory used to create a new User if the id is available otherwise return the User
  /// associated with the id.
  factory User({required String id, required String firstName}) {
    // If user with id already exists, return that object
    if (Users.users.containsKey(id)) {
      // Force casting as non nullable as we already checked that the key exists
      return Users.users[id]!;
    }
    
    // Else, initialize object and save it in Users.users
    final newUser = User._(id: id, firstName: firstName);
    Users.users[id] = newUser;
    return newUser;
  }
}
```

[Try the full code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8067f6eefed9bdae586f58e79e4c8ac7&null_safety=true)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in class to handle things you want. Here's what you can implement.

```
class Player {
  final String name;
  final String color;

  Player(this.name, this.color);

  Player.fromPlayer(Player another) :
    color = another.color,
    name = another.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for caching purposes or you are not creating multiple instances of the `Users` class, I would suggest using a pattern where `static` is responsible for a list of class instances. Sometimes this helps to significantly reduce the amount of code:

```
class User {
  static final Map<String, User> users = {};
  
  final String id, firstName;

  User._({required this.id, required this.firstName});
  
  factory User({required String id, required String firstName}) => users[id] ??= User._(id: id, firstName: firstName);
}
```